# html5 and jquery used for display

Tags: jquery, html, browser

Hi guys can anyone help me on this ...

is there any discrepancy using html 5 in Mozillafirefox,google chrome and safari.In general excluding IE 9.I have been through uploading a video in my site.usinh html5 .

Now the video is played without discrepency.

But the problem i m using the same code the video is visible differently on IE 9 from the rest.

I wonder is there any internal adjustment of the video by browsers.

because my video contains 2 black bars on either sides of the video.this is properly played in IE 9 but only the resolution part is played in rest of the browsers.The code is common for both.

Note : the video is contained in table in html and hover (jquery) is used for the particular table setting.

please do let me know if any clarification
 thank u guys in advance ....

Comment: post code, or make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question about browser differences with HTML5 video:

As you've provided no code I can direct your attention to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) which can show you the current state of support across browsers for the `<video>` tag.

If your video were using the [Ogg/Theora video format](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogv) for instance that could explain why it isn't being supported in IE.

Comment: Hi this is my code:: $("#id.videoThumbnail").html("<video width='360' height='220' onclick='' controls poster='"+data.video.thumbnailURL+"'><source src='" + data.video.mediumBandwidth + "' type='video/mp4'></video>") .there is no problem with IE 9 the problem with the rest 3 browsers

Comment: A full jsfiddle showing the table that the video should be added to, that code, and a link to the video would let folks track down what might be different between browsers. They could also try adding the video to a plain page without the constraints of the table to see if the table plays a role in the difference or not.